# Populating linestring spatial column from easting and northing columns

Tags: mysql, geospatial

Have been trying for a few days now with multiple searches but still unable to make this work. Admittedly i am very new to MySQL and databases in general. I have been able to populate point columns using a similar method in another table and assumed my below code would work.

I have already populated from CSV files my easting and nothings for my 1st point (GDA_X1, GDA_Y1)(in separate decimal columns) and 2nd point (GDA_X2, GDA_Y2) that I wish to join a line between and am now trying to read that data into the linestring function.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Getting error code 1054. Unknown column 'link_geom' in 'field list'

MYSQL CODE:

```sql
alter table pipeline_link_floods_creek add link_geom linestring;
update pipeline_feature_floods_creek
set link_geom = Linestringfromtext(CONCAT('linestring(',pipeline_link_floods_creek.GDA_X1,' ',pipeline_link_floods_creek.GDA_Y1,',',pipeline_link_floods_creek.GDA_X2,' ',pipeline_link_floods_creek.GDA_Y2,')'));
```

Comment: The error you're getting is telling you that the column you tried doesn't exist. Try `alter table pipeline_link_floods_creek add column link_geom linestring;`.

Comment: I can successfully create the column and know this by going in through the workbench and viewing the tables data as well as the alter table command. I can see the name and type of the column is correct. It is the next step when I try and populate this new column that I am failing. It is something to do with the set link_geom = statement

Comment: Oops, looks like the table you're updating `pipeline_feature_floods_creek` doesn't have that column, even if `pipeline_link_floods_creek` does.